# Ckeditor plugin - validating a text field

Tags: ckeditor

I am creating plugin
I have this piece of code below:

What i am trying to do is make sure the email address they enter is valid. 
Just not sure how to stop the onOK if the email address is not valid.

Thanks

This is a code snippet of the plugin

```
contents : [
    {
            id : 'info',
            label : editor.lang.form.title,
            title : editor.lang.form.title,
            elements : [
                    {
                            id : 'destEmail',
                            type : 'text',
                            label : 'Email form results to:',
                            'default' : 'randy@me.com',
                            required : true,
                            accessKey : 'T',
                            commit : function( element )
                            {
                                var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
                                if (this.getValue().search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
                                    alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
                                    return false;
                                }
                                element.setAttribute('id', this.getValue() );
                            }                   
                   }
            ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 12):

Please take a look on [official sample](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_2) and `validate` property. You can write your own validation method at this point.

You can also use [one of the available](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/c98c7a9b216c71e5b3c3cab46604d91e43b80f81/plugins/dialog/plugin.js#L2903-L2999) (still not documented in API). You probably want to do something like this (CKEditor 4):

```
...
validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.regex( /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i, "Please enter a valid email address." );
...
```

It is also possible to combine existing validators and/or write custom validators:

```
function customValidator( x, msg ) {
    return function() {
        var value = this.getValue(),
            pass = !!( CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.integer()( value ) && value < x );

        if ( !pass ) {
            return msg;
        }
    };
}

...   
validate: customValidator( 5, 'Error message when larger than 5.' )
...
```

Comment: Can I combine more validates together? For example now I have `validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.integer('Value must be integer');` and I want to add condition `value < x`. I tried to put this validate into function but it didn't work.

Comment: @juice Just improved the answer. I hope it's helpful.